# Web Scraping with Web-Harvest

Tags: web-scraping, webharvest

I am trying to write a web scraper using web-harvest library to get params from realtor.com. Are there any good tutorials for how to do it?  I am using the eclipse IDE

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: http://masochismtango.com/2010/02/15/webharvest-web-scraping-from-java/